# How do I make select option of only one select field display another div when multiple select fields are present

Tags: jquery, html

I want a section of a form displayed only when certain select options are selected. I have been able to achieve this using the following html code and jquery script

```js
$(document).ready(function displayform() {

  //var dept = $("#dept option:selected").text();

  $('select').change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() != 'administration') {
      $('#teacred').show();
    } else {
      $('#teacred').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="department" class="col-md-4 control-label">Department</label>

  <div class="col-md-6">
    <select name="department" id="dept" class="form-control" required autofocus>
            <option class="text-muted">-- Select Department --</option>
            <option value="administration">Adminstration</option>
            <option value="ict">ICT</option>
        </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group" id="position">
  <label for="position" class="col-md-4 control-label">Position</label>

  <div class="col-md-6">
    <select name="position" class="form-control" required autofocus>
            <option></option>
            <option value="hod">Head of Department</option>
            <option value="staff">Staff</option>
        </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-12" id="teacred">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="username" class="col-md-4 control-label">Username</label>

    <div class="col-md-6">
      <input id="username" type="username" class="form-control" name="username" value="{{ old('username') }}" required>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The challenge is that while the code works when i select a department, selecting a position also affects the display of the teacred div. How do i ensure that only the dept select options will determine when the teacred div is shown or hidden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('select')` will select all `<select>` elements which is not what you want, change to 2nd select triggered the change event and showing `$('#teacred')`

#### Solution: use `$('#dept')` to target the select for department only.

```js
$(document).ready(function displayform() {

  //var dept = $("#dept option:selected").text();

  $('#dept').change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() != 'administration') {
      $('#teacred').show();
    } else {
      $('#teacred').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="department" class="col-md-4 control-label">Department</label>

  <div class="col-md-6">
    <select name="department" id="dept" class="form-control" required autofocus>
            <option class="text-muted">-- Select Department --</option>
            <option value="administration">Adminstration</option>
            <option value="ict">ICT</option>
        </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group" id="position">
  <label for="position" class="col-md-4 control-label">Position</label>

  <div class="col-md-6">
    <select name="position" class="form-control" required autofocus>
            <option></option>
            <option value="hod">Head of Department</option>
            <option value="staff">Staff</option>
        </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-12" id="teacred">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="username" class="col-md-4 control-label">Username</label>

    <div class="col-md-6">
      <input id="username" type="username" class="form-control" name="username" value="{{ old('username') }}" required>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great! That fixed it. Thanks